# How would I continue a "for loop" of 1 to 360 in this scenario dealing with pointers and addresses?

Tags: c++, pointers, for-loop, iostream, memory-address

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
int main() {

    int start = 0;
    for (int* i = &start; i <= (&start + 360); i++) {
        *i = 20;
        cout << "address: " << i << "   contains: " << *i << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I removed the `*i = 20` line it only printed `cout << "address: " << i << "   contains: " << *i << "\n";` once. Also may someone clear up addresses and pointers if necessary in a "beginner friendly" summary. What is the problem?

Comment: `int` is only 4 bytes. `i` is surely exploring the dark abyss.

Comment: This causes undefined behavior. You are handling memory addresses that don't belong to you!

Comment: It's undefined behavior and thus beyond explanation.

Comment: Oh alright so i have to deal with memory addresses that I have noted only.   ~ just learning cpp now with this stuff today.

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.  Irenically, in this code, it's much shorter to write `std::` in the one place you need it!

Answer (score 3):

```
int* i = &start
```

**This is valid.**  You are creating a pointer to data that genuinely exists.

```
i++
*i = 20;
```

**This is not valid.  It is called "Undefined Behavior".**  You don't know where `i` points now.

C++ will not stop you from doing this.  It will not prevent you from doing something that doesn't make sense.  It is your responsibility to make sure that a pointer points to data that you can account for.

Comment: Hopefully, though, your teammates/boss/conscience will stop you from doing it :)

Answer (score 1):

Pointers can be tricky, here's an analogy: a pointer is like a string attached to a buried treasure, you can follow it and find it. It is the "string," and explicitly NOT the "treasure."

The string here is the memory address of what you're storing. And the data is the treasure. The data could be anything, but a pointer is always an address.

As such, you can do math with pointers. Here's a summary of what's actually going on in the code:

`int start = 0;` This line is creating a local variable that will hold an integer. This automatically allocates memory in the current stack frame (not super important what this means exactly, but the data does have to live somewhere).

The first time the loop runs, `int* i = &start` executes and now you've made a pointer `i` which points to the address of `start` (syntax `&foo` will yield the address of `foo` as opposed to the value of `foo`). The address of `start` is in your current stack frame, which your program can access. The syntax `*i` is called "de-referencing", which is a fancy way of saying "following the string to the treasure" (i.e. go to the address and fetch the value held there or set the value there).

Also, the condition `i <= (&start + 360)` is actually checking that the address `i` represents is less than 360 addresses away from that of start. I'm not sure if that's what you wanted or not, but explained for clarity.

After one iteration, the `i++` executes. Remember, `i` is a pointer, which means it's an address. So that code is actually incrementing the address, not the data. Because `i` is specifically an `int` pointer, adding 1 to it will move the address up by 4 bytes (the size of an `int`).

Once you've moved `i`, attempting to dereference it means going to a different address that is no longer the address that holds `start`.

Now, admittedly this is where it gets much hazier (at least in my mind), because pointer bugs are a nightmare. Usually, pointer issues are due to trying to dereference a null pointer (not the case here as your pointer definitely has a value), or trying to access memory that you aren't allowed to. In this case I believe it's the latter. Because you incremented the pointer `i`, you're moved the address and are now attempting to set the value at the location (`*i = 20`), which is likely causing an error or strange behavior.

Hopefully that helps clarify pointers a bit and explain the source of you errors.

Comment: thanks so from all answers, i just cant access whatever and memory i'm trying to access. ;p    ~ also do you have any good sources for C++ i've been jumping around alot of sources and books especially from this one post here that had a listing of books but sometimes the references still can be tedious.

Answer (score 0):

The tool for diagnosing invalid memory accesses is Valgrind.  Let's see what happens when we ask it to run your program:

```
valgrind -q ./50361830
```

```
address: 0x1fff000704   contains: 20
==19096== Invalid read of size 4
==19096==    at 0x1088F4: main (50361830.cpp:10)
==19096==  Address 0x1f00000014 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==19096== 
==19096== 
==19096== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==19096==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x1F00000014
==19096==    at 0x1088F4: main (50361830.cpp:10)
```

So we get one successful output (when we have written to `start`) and then the second time around the loop, we attempt to access memory we don't own.  Immediately after that, the process is killed due to an invalid access.

What has likely happened here is that the write to the address after `start` has overwritten part of the local variable `i` (notice that the address ends with `00000014` - that's decimal `20`), so now `i` is pointing somewhere it shouldn't.